# Creating a .Net Application in IIS via web.config is possible?

Tags: .net, iis, iis-8, iis-8.5

At the company I work for, development team has a subdomain pointed to a IIS website, example myteam.company, and the IIS servers are maintained by a infrastructure team. Every request we have for IIS server we must open a ticket for the other team (but the configs that we can do via web.config). All deployments are done via shared folder (yeah, we know that is far from good, but works at least).

So, every project, classic ASP and PHP, is done via a subdirectory, that responds as myteam.company/project1 , myteam.company/project2 and so on.

The problem is with .Net applications, because at this point we must open a ticket to infra team in order to convert one of the subdirectories into a application (.Net).

Is there a way for creating a .Net Application in IIS via web.config? It would be important so that creating could be delegated for development team in our company case.

Comment: Impossible. Please use other approaches.